# Can extensions be installed in Watir's Firefox browser?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to use Watir on a page that has a large number of ads and it's really slowing down my tests. Why when Watir launches Firefox do my extensions (Adblock, etc.) not carry over and is it possible to install them?

Comment: Since you are using Firefox, I think it is watir-webdriver. You can try to use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604682/firefox-webdriver-installing-p‌​lugin-during-the-execution/14618915#14618915) to use the addon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. Let' assume you to want use Firebug extension..

First download the Firebug xpi file, then use the following code:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.add_extension "../path/to/firebug.xpi"
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```